# Second to last word

Tags: clojure

Grab the input file, and output the second to last word on every line.

Can I make it shorter and/or more efficient?
I'm surprised by the performance. While the runtime, +2s, is likely dominated by start up, it also requires +40M.

```
(use 'clojure.java.io)
(use '[clojure.string :only (join split)])

(with-open [rdr (reader (first *command-line-args*))]
  (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]
    (println
      (nth (split line #" ") (- (count (split line #" ")) 2)))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Lein to run? Or straight Java? Either way, I think the memory use is normal even for a hello world program.

Following are some naive timings (I didn't run them many times). Here is my baseline hello world (uses about 30M). My computer is quite slow btw :):

> ```
> C:\george\test\secondtolast>timemem cmd /c lein run
> Helloooooooooo world.
> Exit code      : 0
> Elapsed time   : 8.31
> Kernel time    : 0.03 (0.4%)
> User time      : 0.03 (0.4%)
> page fault #   : 762
> Working set    : 2864 KB
> Paged pool     : 69 KB
> Non-paged pool : 2 KB
> Page file size : 2088 KB
> ```

Next is a baseline with my working corpus (Paradise Lost, 11404 lines of text and about 500 kb). I just output the first line (uses about 30M):

> ```
> C:\george\test\secondtolast>timemem cmd /c lein run
> ?The Project Gutenberg EBook of Paradise Lost, by John Milton
> Exit code      : 0
> Elapsed time   : 8.45
> Kernel time    : 0.11 (1.3%)
> User time      : 0.03 (0.4%)
> page fault #   : 762
> Working set    : 2864 KB
> Paged pool     : 69 KB
> Non-paged pool : 2 KB
> Page file size : 2088 KB
> ```

As you can see the time doesn't change much. Here is your program (about same memory):

> ```
> [11k+ lines of output]
> Exit code      : 0
> Elapsed time   : 10.98
> Kernel time    : 0.05 (0.4%)
> User time      : 0.02 (0.1%)
> page fault #   : 762
> Working set    : 2864 KB
> Paged pool     : 69 KB
> Non-paged pool : 2 KB
> Page file size : 2088 KB
> ```

A little more time but not much. Finally here is a little different version of that code (about same memory):

> ```
> Exit code      : 0
> Elapsed time   : 9.13
> Kernel time    : 0.13 (1.4%)
> User time      : 0.02 (0.2%)
> page fault #   : 762
> Working set    : 2864 KB
> Paged pool     : 69 KB
> Non-paged pool : 2 KB
> Page file size : 2088 KB
> ```

I'm not convinced it's actually faster (it would need many more trials), I think really it is about the same. But maybe you can think about using subvec (http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/subvec ) or something similar. Nth is O(n), while subvec is O(1), though in reality these are not very long lines.

```clj
(ns secondtolast.core
  (require [clojure.java.io :as io]
           [clojure.string :refer [join split]])
  (:gen-class))


(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  []
  (with-open [rdr (io/reader "pg20.txt")]
    (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]
      (let [words (split line #" ")
            c (count words)]
        (if-not (or (empty? line) (= 1 c))
          (println (last (subvec words 0 (- c 1))))
          line)))))
```

Comment: Nth is only O(n) when used on a list (they are just linked lists) but when nth is used on a vector it is actually O(logn) where the log base is 32. In true big-O the base just disappears, but in practice having a log base of 32 pretty much makes nth a O(1) call. I would guess that since you are able to use subvec (which only works on vectors), the cost of calling nth would not be O(n).

Comment: @jjcomer Quite. It's not the [`subvec`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/subvec) that's taking the time; it's the [`last`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/last), which is linear in the length of its argument. So replace `(last (subvec words 0 (- c 1)))` with `(nth words (- c 2))`.